# ant junit batchtest from a jar

Tags: ant, junit

I'd like to use ant (post 1.7) to run all tests in classes named *Test.class in a certain jar.

Something like the following (although it doesn't actually run any tests):

```
    <junit fork="yes" printsummary="on" haltonfailure="on">
        <formatter type="xml"/>
        <batchtest fork="yes" todir="${junit.output.dir}">
            <resources>
               <zipentry zipfile="tests-only.jar" name="**/*Test.class"/>
            </resources> 
        </batchtest>            
        <classpath refid="testsplus.classpath"/>
    </junit>
```

What is the correct syntax for the resources/zipentry part?

The ant docs say:

> batchtest collects the included
>   resources from any number of nested
>   Resource Collections. It then
>   generates a test class name for each
>   resource that ends in .java or .class.
>
> Any type of Resource Collection is
>   supported as a nested element, prior
>   to Ant 1.7 only `<fileset>` has been
>   supported.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Instead of `zipentry` you can probably use the `zipfileset` datatype:

```
<zipfileset src="tests-only.jar" includes="**/*Test.class"/>
```

Comment: i am facing ClassNotFoundException when i tried to run the junit inside a jar file. Can you please find any solution for this issue ?

Comment: @jugi You'll have to provide a bit more detail!